# How can I consolidate two case-different git directories in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

In a recent code clean-up I've managed to move some files into a directory which differs from the existing directory only by it's case.

With the repo checked out, I see all the files checked out in the upper-case version. If, however, I now try and rename one of the files in the lower-case directories, I'm unable to do so because TortoiseGit complains the file doesn't exist.

How do I move all the files in the lower case directory into an upper case directory to correct the issue?

**Edit** - A quick illustration of the problem...

My repo looks like this:

```
\software
    \unit_tests
        \file1.h
        \file1.cpp
    \UNIT_TESTS
        \file2.h
        \file2.cpp
```

In Windows I see this when I check the repository out:

```
\software
    \UNIT_TESTS
        \file1.h
        \file1.cpp
        \file2.h
        \file2.cpp
```

If I now try and move `file1.h` somewhere else I get an error stating that it's not under version control.

Comment: So, your question is how to rename a folder called e.g. "_folder_" to "_folDer_"?

Comment: Added an example. I want to consolidate the two into `unit_tests` - all in lower case to avoid any issues in the future.

Comment: Thank you. _Windows_ is case insensitive in terms of filenames so it merged your folders into one. I'm afraid you can't do it on _Windows_ (I am not a _git_ expert) unless there's a way to work directly on the repo (without involving the _Windows_ FS). If there's no way you can get a _Unix_ machine to get the job done, as a workaround you could give [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I now try and move file1.h somewhere else I get an error stating that it's not under version control.

You have to make sure to use the proper casing (i.e. the one Git knows about) when using Git commands. While the Windows file system is case insensitive, Git is not, so you should use the correct paths there.

So while Windows sees the files in the same directory, you still have the following paths known to Git:

```
software\unit_tests\file1.h
software\unit_tests\file1.cpp
software\UNIT_TESTS\file2.h
software\UNIT_TESTS\file2.cpp
```

So in order to move those files, you have to use those paths exactly. And you might want to use a temporary location in between, so that Windows will handle it correctly when you perform the move in Git, e.g.:

```
git mv software\unit_tests\file1.h software\unit_tests2\file1.h
git mv software\unit_tests2\file1.h software\UNIT_TESTS\file1.h
```

Alternatively, you can also skip the physical move, and just remove the file from the `unit_tests` directoy and add them to `UNIT_TESTS` instead:

```
git rm --cached software\unit_tests\file1.h
git add software\UNIT_TESTS\file1.h
```

Comment: Would removing and re-adding preserve the history (i.e. mark it as a move)?

Comment: Git technically does not record file moves, when you do `git mv` it’s essentially a combination of `rm` and `add`. The recognition of moves is just done on the front end, so yeah, the effect is the same.